# Extract information from lines and columns in PERL

Tags: arrays, perl

I have a huge file with multiple lines and columns. Each line has many columns and many lines have the same name in the same position. E.g.

```
 A  C  Z  Y  X
 A  C  E  J
 B  E  K  L  M
```

What is the best way to Find all lines that share the same items in a certain position? For instance, I would like to know that there are 2 A, 2 C, 1 D, etc., all ordered by column.

I am **really** new to Perl, and so I am struggling a lot to advance in this so any tips are appreciated.

I got to this point:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w

use strict; 

my $path='My:\Path\To\My\File.txt';
my $columns;
my $line;

open (FILE,$path), print "Opened!\n" or die ("Error opening");

while (<FILE>)
{
@line=split('\t',$_);
}

close FILE;
```

The output of this can be another TSV, that examines the file only until the 5th column, ordered from top to bottom, like:

```
 A  2
 C  2
 Z  1
 Y  1
 E  1
 J  1
 B  1
 E  1
 K  1
 L  1
```

Note that the first items appear first and, when shared among lines, do not show again for subsequent lines.

Edit: as per the questions in the comments, I changed the dataset and output. Note that two E appear: one belonging to the third column, the other belonging to the second column.

Edit2: Alternatively, this could also be analyzed column by column, thus showing the results in the first column, then in the second, and so on, as long as they were clearly separated. Something like

```
 "1st" "col"
 A 2
 B 1
 "2nd" "col"
 C 2
 E 1
 "3rd" "col"
 Z 1
 E 1
 K 1
 "4th" "col"
 Y 1
 J 1
 L 1
```

Comment: Please show the output you would like to see.

Comment: @Borodin done, I hope it is clear now

Comment: So if a symbol occurs, it will always be in the same position? (Then why is position at all relevant in the requirements? Just say you want to count symbols?)

Comment: @tripleee, it may happen that some lines share some same names, but cannot be grouped because they are in different columns. e.g. `A B E` and `X E Z`. In this case, I would like to count both `E` as different positions

Comment: Well, I'm thinking the distinction between positions would be complicated to implement

Comment: As [Borodin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin) asked earlier, please show your wanted output--especially in light of the new specs.  You'll need to modify your sample dataset to do this...

Comment: @Kenosis Ok, I think it may be clearer now. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Yes, it is clearer now--thank you.  The script's updated to produce your wanted output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not fully understand the formatting of your desired output, so the below script outputs all the data from the first col on the first row, and so on.  This can easily be modified to the format that you desire, but is a quick starting point to how to acummulate the data first and then processing it.

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $path='My:\Path\To\My\File.txt';

open my $fh, '<', $path;

my @data;

# while (<$fh>) { Switch these lines when ready for real data
while (<DATA>) {
    my @row = split ' ';
    for my $col (0..$#row) {
        $data[$col]{$row[$col]}++;
    }
}

for my $coldata (@data) {
    for my $letter (sort keys %$coldata) {
        print "$letter $coldata->{$letter} ";
    }
    print "\n";
}

close $fh;

__DATA__
A  C  Z  Y  X
A  C  D  J
B  E  K  L  M
```

Outputs

```
A 2 B 1
C 2 E 1
D 1 K 1 Z 1
J 1 L 1 Y 1
M 1 X 1
```

Comment: thanks for the help. Please see my edits for updates! thanks again

Comment: @Sosi  My output already separates the data by column.  The first column is in the 1st row, 2nd col in 2nd row, etc.

Comment: one small remark (or maybe I'm understanding wrong): where you split lines by ' ', you should replace with '\t'  since they are tab separated. I used spaces in my example to avoid writing '\t' everywhere

Comment: @Sosi `split ' '` is a special case which is actually equivalent to `split /\s+/` with the additional benefit of skipping any leading whitespace.  Just read the [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) docs for details.   In otherwords, it'll take care of tabs too.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $path = 'My:\Path\To\My\File.txt';
my %hash;

open my $fh, '<', $path or die $!;

while (<$fh>) {
    my @cols = split ' ', $_, 5;
    $hash{$_}{ $cols[$_] || '' }++ for 0 .. 3;
}

close $fh;

for my $key ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys %hash ) {
    print "Col ", $key + 1, "\n";
    print "$_ $hash{$key}{$_}\n"
      for sort { $hash{$key}->{$b} <=> $hash{$key}->{$a} } grep $_,
      keys %{ $hash{$key} };
}
```

Output on your dataset:

```
Col 1
A 2
B 1
Col 2
C 2
E 1
Col 3
Z 1
K 1
E 1
Col 4
J 1
L 1
Y 1
```